# output emacs buffer to another terminal window

Tags: emacsclient, multi-term

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a terminal windows running emacs talk to each other (running in a server environment)

For example:

- Open an instance of emacs in one terminal window.
- Open up a second terminal window to connect to the first one and display an output buffer (eg, `*Messages*`)
- Any action on the first terminal will be outputted on the second terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a standard server-client environment that is built in emacs. Just add into your emacs config this line:

```
(server-start)
```

This starts the emacs server when you first launch emacs. It works in both graphical emacs and within terminal.

Next you go to an other terminal window and launch emacsclient to connect to the server. If the first instance was graphical, use option `-nw` force opening inside the terminal. Now you have two views into same emacs instance and they naturally share buffers.

Comment: that was really easy to do. thanks!